# Adding Macrium Bootable iso to Blu Ray with recovery files

Tags: boot, iso-image, burning, blu-ray, macrium

I recently just consolidated my recovery DVD set from five DVD's to one 25 GB Blu-Ray. I am trying to see if I can include the bootable Macrium iso on to the Blu-ray by simply adding it to the directory that I store the recovery iso's and running the usual "growisofs" command and simply burning it on to the blu-ray? It would be nice to just have one Blu-Ray Disc, insert it, boot from it, and then be able to restore my computer from the files on it without ever having to swap discs. Is this obtainable? If so, how? And am I on the right track?

Comment: (reCAPTCHA does not let me post answers. So as comment:)
You could try to first burn the bootable ISO as image, leave the medium
appendable (no growisofs option -dao or -dvd-compat),
<pre><code>
growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=bootable_image.iso
</code></pre>
and then add the other ISOs (or their unpacked files) in a second session.

Comment: The only issue I would have with that is that I am using a BD-R, not a BD-RE, so I am not sure I am able to leave the Blu-Ray appendable or not after the first burning.

Comment: Just do not use a growisofs option that causes closing. The uncertainty is rather whether El Torito will continue to use sector 17 of the first session as boot sector. You will only know if it still boots after adding the second session.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to this question took some time, but I was able to find a workable solution. Essentially, the easiest way to combine all of the data discs AND the boot disc in to one bootable .iso, is to create a file ON the boot disc that contains the data discs and then run OSCDIMG.exe to make it bootable. From here, you can then boot off the blu-ray and then provide the path to the Data discs from which to begin the recovery. 
Because all of the information I needed was stored on a Linux server, but I had to use a Windows Command Prompt, I had to map the network to my command prompt. I did this by using the "net use DRIVE: PATH /user:USERNAME PASSWORD" command. Once I had a path to the network where my information was stored, I was able to proceed.
Do note, that if you do not have the OSCDIMG executable installed, you will need to do so and then make sure that it is moved to C:\Windows\System32 so that it is usable.
Once I had installed and moved the executable, I was able to run the OSCDIMG command which looked something like this:

oscdimg -m -o -u2 -udfver102 -bootdata:2#p0,e,bV:\TIBs\V4.1.1\Boot\etfsboot.com#pEF,e,bV:\TIBs\V4.1.1\Boot\efisys.bin V:\TIBs\V4.1.1 V:\TIBs\iso\testbootAlpha.iso

A breakdown of the individual commands can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947024/how-to-create-an-iso-image-for-uefi-platforms-for-a-windows-pe-cd-rom

Once this .iso was created and stored on my Linux server, I was able to run the typical "growisofs" command, burn it to a blu-ray, successfully boot off it in to the Macrium environment (which is what I prefer to use), and locate the files. I could then run my recovery fully, without ever having to change discs.

Hopefully this shows you how to create a bootable disc that stores all of your recovery data AND boot disc on the same disc. This saves a lot of time (constantly swapping discs) and money (buying  a couple stacks of Blu-Rays instead of bulk DVD's). Any questions you may have, feel free to comment on and I will try my best to provide some clarity.